# How can I send username and password to an express server with ajax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

This is the ajax method to send the form to server:

```
$("#submit").click( function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/login',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data: $('#submit-form').serialize(),
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {},
        success: function(data) {               
             console.log('Success');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             // alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
             console.log(this.data);
             console.log('Error', textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

The following is my index.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    console.log('body=', req.body);
    res.end('{"success" : "Success", "status" : 200}');
});
```

But i'm only getting 'Error' and sometimes the server gets the POST and sometimes not, why and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).serialize()` should be referencing your form (e.g., `$('#my-form').serialize()`).

from https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

> It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`

if that is indeed your form and you still have issues, what is the value of `textStatus` and `errorThrown` in the **error** callback? does the request reach the `console.log('Login request')` statement?

the following express code works for me:

```
...
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  console.log('body=', req.body)
})
...
```

with the following AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/login',
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  data: $('#form').serialize(),
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  username: $('#username').val(),
  password: $('#password').val(),
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {},
  success: function(data) {               
      console.log('Success');
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
      console.log('Error', textStatus, errorThrown)
  }
})
```

**EDIT** added sample express & ajax code

Comment: The value of textStatus and errorThrown is "error error " and the request does not reach the Login Request statement.

Comment: I changed data to `$('# submit-form').serialize()` and I added a `console.log (this.data, this.url, this.type);` to beforeSend that prints `username=johnny&password=john123 /login POST`

Comment: If i send through html using `... method="POST" action="/login">` the client receives the token, but with ajax i can handle error/success directly.

Comment: I also removed username/password field, but the app.post is never called.

Comment: what does your `/login` express route look like. what `body-parser` are you using in your express app? for example: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`

Comment: i have edited my answer and added express and ajax code snippets that are working for me

Comment: HTML form: `<form id="submit-form" class="form-group">`

Comment: The route is `app.post('/login', login.signin(app));` and i'm using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))` and `app.use(bodyParser.json());'

Comment: @J.Ricardo with multiple bodyParsers you should add the content type to your AJAX request (e.g., `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`) the `serialize()` creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation . see updated example above.

Comment: Thanks, but sometimes works, sometimes not, i'll update the code.

Comment: be sure to always add the right **content-type** (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json`) to your AJAX requests. when your form has `method="POST" action="/login"` the browser is automatically adding the correct content-type when sending the form